# Unable to run JSF application on websphere 6.1

Tags: java, websphere, jsf-1.2, websphere-6.1

First I created **JSF1.2 and JDBC project on tomcat 6 server using Apache MyFaces JSF Core 1.2**.

After that I created **.WAR file of my project using eclipse > export > WAR**

Then I deployed my **.WAR file on WebSphere 6.1 server and i am facing below issue.**

**Application Browser**

[image]

**Console**

```
[7/4/13 7:44:24:871 EDT] 00000021 CacheManager  I org.ajax4jsf.cache.CacheManager getCacheFactory Selected [org.ajax4jsf.cache.LRUMapCacheFactory] cache factory
[7/4/13 7:44:24:873 EDT] 00000021 LRUMapCacheFa I org.ajax4jsf.cache.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache Creating LRUMap cache instance using parameters: {org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT=false, javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext=resources.application, org.richfaces.SKIN=classic, org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT=true, javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD=client, org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL=true, org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML=true}
[7/4/13 7:44:24:873 EDT] 00000021 LRUMapCacheFa I org.ajax4jsf.cache.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache Creating LRUMap cache instance of default capacity
[7/4/13 7:44:24:889 EDT] 00000021 CacheManager  I org.ajax4jsf.cache.CacheManager getCacheFactory Selected [org.ajax4jsf.cache.LRUMapCacheFactory] cache factory
[7/4/13 7:44:24:889 EDT] 00000021 LRUMapCacheFa I org.ajax4jsf.cache.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache Creating LRUMap cache instance using parameters: {org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT=false, javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext=resources.application, org.richfaces.SKIN=classic, org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT=true, javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD=client, org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL=true, org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML=true}
[7/4/13 7:44:24:889 EDT] 00000021 LRUMapCacheFa I org.ajax4jsf.cache.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache Creating LRUMap cache instance of default capacity
[7/4/13 7:44:24:939 EDT] 00000021 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: Faces Servlet. Exception thrown : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/faces/render/ResponseStateManager.getState(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreView(AjaxStateManager.java:436)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:310)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:91)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1219)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)

[7/4/13 7:44:24:950 EDT] 00000021 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\WTE_APPSRV611\logs\ffdc\server1_00000021_13.07.04_07.44.24_0.txt
[7/4/13 7:44:24:963 EDT] 00000021 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\WTE_APPSRV611\logs\ffdc\server1_00000021_13.07.04_07.44.24_0.txt
[7/4/13 7:44:24:969 EDT] 00000021 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl open FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\WTE_APPSRV611\logs\ffdc\server1_00000021_13.07.04_07.44.24_1.txt
[7/4/13 7:44:24:987 EDT] 00000021 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\WTE_APPSRV611\logs\ffdc\server1_00000021_13.07.04_07.44.24_1.txt
[7/4/13 7:44:24:988 EDT] 00000021 BaseXMLFilter E org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter doXmlFilter Exception in the filter chain
                                 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/faces/render/ResponseStateManager.getState(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1331)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/faces/render/ResponseStateManager.getState(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreView(AjaxStateManager.java:436)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:310)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:91)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1219)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)

[7/4/13 7:44:25:014 EDT] 00000021 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl open FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\WTE_APPSRV611\logs\ffdc\server1_00000021_13.07.04_07.44.25_0.txt
[7/4/13 7:44:25:021 EDT] 00000021 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\WTE_APPSRV611\logs\ffdc\server1_00000021_13.07.04_07.44.25_0.txt
[7/4/13 7:44:25:022 EDT] 00000021 WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/faces/render/ResponseStateManager.getState(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreView(AjaxStateManager.java:436)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:310)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:91)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1219)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
```

Please help me into this.

Comment: There can be many reasons for this. Tomcat and Websphere are two completely different products. Websphere is a JEE application server, while tomcat is not. In other words, websphere already ships with JSF, seems to be 1.1: http://www.martinahrer.at/2008/08/14/websphere-61-and-jsf-12/ If you bundle your war with MyFaces 1.2, classloading issues are sure to arise. You should read about how to deploy a JSF application on Websphere.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a claassloading issue. Since Websphere ships with JSF and its subdependencies, probably they are mixing qith the ones you are providing in your application.

Please have a look into this guide, there is a section for Websphere 6.1

http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Websphere_Installation

Setting the classloaders to application first (or parent last, which is the same) and restarting your application should do the work